# Ignore log entries in Stryker mutation test

Tags: c#, .net, mutation-testing, stryker, stryker-net

I'm adding `Stryker.net` to my C# project. I see that it mutates on all log entries. Is there any way I can ignore these in the config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on how your logging looks like, but most probably you can play with the `ignore-methods` [option](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/Configuration/#ignore-methods).

For example,
`dotnet stryker -im "['Logger.Log']"`
or even just
`dotnet stryker -im "['*Log']"`

Comment: Separate issue, but do you know if that option is available for other languages than .NET, as I do not see it in the documentation for Javascript, for instance.

Comment: I don't know, from the docs doesn't seem so. You can ask in their [discussions](https://github.com/stryker-mutator/stryker-net/discussions) though, the guys are responsive. Also, please mark the answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: I didn't ask the question, so I cannot accept it.  I did ask the follow up question on slack.

Comment: Or, I didn't notice a different nickname! Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a valid solution, when for logging you are using the interface **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<>**.

Create a file named **stryker-config.json** in the root of your tests project.
Populate it with the following:

```
{
  "stryker-config": {
    "ignore-methods": [
      "*LogCrititcal*",
      "*LogDebug*",
      "*LogError*",
      "*LogInformation*",
      "*LogTrace*",
      "*LogWarning*"
    ]
  }
}
```

This configuration will ignore the methods of the interface.

Comment: `Log*` would be valid as well